# Firebase realtime database profiler counts list calls twice

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

When using the Firebase realtime database profiler, I saw that it counted my queries twice a lot of the time. I found out that everytime I call a list, the profiler tells me that the data is retrieved twice. Everytime I call an object, it's only retrieved once. By the way, if I console.log() the results, it will only log it once. It's only the profiler that shows a count of 2.

An example:

```
this.db.object(`/blogs/Birdee`).valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe();
```

Leads to:

[image: Data retrieved when using an object]

And

```
this.db.list(`/blogs/Birdee`).valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe();
```

Leads to:

[image: Data retrieved when using a list]

I can't figure out why this happens. Anybody has an idea?

Thanks